# Can I synch a copy of a file placed in another folder to the parent file?

Tags: sharepoint-server, synchronisation

Suppose there is a parent file that is kept up-to-date, placed in folder X from Department X.
Another department Y wants the same file being available in their own team's folder Y, but making sure it stays in synch when the parent file is updated. Is this possible?

Comment: What SharePoint version? Why can't department Y just access the file in folder X ? (You can use a document link)

Answer (score 0):

What's the version of SharePoint you used?

If you use SharePoint Online and SharePoint 2016 and later, there is a feature "Copy" will sync the document in multiple places.

More information check the article: [Keep Your Documents in Sync with SharePoint Copy](https://lydonsolutions.com/2018/11/06/documents-sync-sharepoint-copy/)